# How to fit regression model by group in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fit xgboost model on a dataset based on a group of variables.

Here is the reproducible code.

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,3,1000),
               'B':np.random.randint(1,3,1000),
               'C':np.random.uniform(1,10,1000),
               'D':np.random.uniform(1,25,1000),
               'E':np.random.uniform(10,50,1000),
               'F':np.random.uniform(5,250,1000)})
```

This is the mock up data. Here I want to run this model based on columns 'A' and 'B'.

```
seed = 7
test_size = 0.33
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train.iloc[:,:-1],     train.iloc[:,-1], test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
```

Here I am splitting data into test and train datasets.

```
models = []
def xgb_model_fit(x):
    xg_reg=xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear',colsample_bytree = 0.3, learning_rate = 0.1,max_depth = 5,alpha = 10,n_estimators = 10)
    xg_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
    models.append([x.name,xg_reg])
```

Group by variable list is

```
gb = ['A','B']
```

Model building step is

```
X_train.groupby(gb,as_index=False).apply(xgb_model_fit)
```

Now I want to use the fitted models on test data on their respected group.

Question1:

In test data, my first group is (1,1). Now I want to use (1,1) group fitted model on test data group same group and then have to get fitted values. How to do this?

Question2:

Is there any direct way to fit model by group instead of running model for each group?

how can I do this task?